# Formatting Excel sheets from Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formatting, data-manipulation

I'm using the following code to print a dataframe to a csv;

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dataframe.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='dataframe')

writer.save()
```

But my df is about 200 columns wide (20 columns of 10 categories) and only 5 rows deep.

Is there any way of manipulating it so that you tell pandas where to print various columns in the excel file.

Eg. Print columns 1-10 on row 1 in the excel sheet. Print columns 11-20 on row 6 in the excel sheet. etc.

Really I'm just trying to do the formatting of the excel file in pandas as opposed to having to play with the excel sheet after.

Comment: Why not transposing the dataset instead ?

Comment: Hmm, yes I hadn’t actually thought of this which is obviously an easy solution. Works for time being! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution might be to transpose the dataset using [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dataframe.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='dataframe')

writer.save()
```